# Can I use session id from chrome cookies to access salesforce API?

Tags: rest-api, extension, session-id

I'm in the process of developing my own Chrome extension for personal use, aiming to streamline my daily tasks effectively. This extension will be akin to Salesforce Inspector but will be tailored to my needs, ensuring a simpler interface and only incorporating features that are pertinent to my routine.

Presently, my focus is on identifying the optimal approach for accessing the Salesforce Rest API, mirroring the functionality of Salesforce Inspector. I am keen on avoiding the creation of a connected app or the need to log in every time I launch the extension. As far as my understanding goes, Inspector employs the Session Id (sid) from the page cookies as authorization for its requests.

In my attempt to replicate this process, I successfully logged into Salesforce, accessed the DevTools, navigated to the Application tab, scrutinized the cookies, and specifically filtered by sid. The result, as illustrated here: [image], seemed promising.

Encouraged by this discovery, I endeavored to access the Rest API using the identified sid in my request's Authorization header, following the pattern Bearer . However, my efforts were met with an error, specifically the **INVALID_SESSION_ID** code.

In an attempt to troubleshoot, I experimented with converting the sid to base64 format, only to encounter the same error once again.

My question is whether utilizing the sid from cookies is a feasible approach, or if there is an alternative method I should explore. Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you're in Lightning or not. Lightning sessions do not have API access, as a security measure. If you're in Classic (e.g. Visualforce), that session Id will have valid API access. Since Classic is being phased out, you should avoid trying to use such a session. For API access, consider using an [OAuth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5) to gain access. Use [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/identity) to initialize the flow and get the access token back.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
What I see from the docs for OAuth you shared, it requires user to login with credentials from the extension. I try to avoid this scenario if possible, are there any other ways?

Comment: @senoron If they're already logged in to Salesforce, OAuth should reuse that session. They would only need to grant access to the app, if they haven't already.

Comment: thanks, I will check that

Comment: I see OAuth flow method requires connected app configured on the org. My idea is to use the extension on different orgs without any additional configurations or installations, just like salesforce inspector

Comment: @senoron You don't need to have the Connected App installed in the target org. It does so automatically. The users literally need to click a button one time.